# Return to first Activity on ActionBar home click but only recreate it if it has been destroyed: which flags should I use?

Tags: android

I have set `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` to true and when home is pressed I want the user to go back to the very first `Activity`.

But in case `FirstActivity` already is created I don't want to recreate it. I'm currently adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the intent that starts `FirstActivity`. Are there other flags I need to add (or use another flag altogether)
 to get the desired behaviour of only creating the `Activity` if it doesn't exist or is the flag I have sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use singleTop launchmode and override onNewIntent method (this will be called if activity is relaunched instead of new one )

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. do you mean set singleTop on the Activity in the Manifest?

Comment: Yes for that activity only.

Answer (score 0):

you can't assume that root activity is still alive, In Android 4.0 and greater devices have the developer option called don't keep activities, if it's enabled when you leave from one activity to another the parent activity automatically killed by the system.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out which flags to use so that if the activity has been killed it is recreated, but if it hasn't been killed the 'old' instance is resumed. Any advice on which intent flags to use for this scenario is appreciated.